# How to use multiple if conditions in Awk?

Tags: awk

I am quite new to Awk and I have a following query.

input.csv

```
"11111","TRUE","aa"
"456789","TRUE","aa;bb;cc"
"2345","TRUE","bb"
"434566","","cc"
```

I am trying to create an awk command which should give me following output:

output.csv

```
"11111","TRUE","aa,,"
"456789","TRUE","aa,bb,cc"
"2345","TRUE",",bb,"
"434566","",",,cc"
```

I need first two arguments to be printed every time but the third one is which I need to check. So third attribute can have any of the aa,bb,cc or combination of these like aa;bb or aa;cc or aa;bb;cc or none of these so I need to make sure which of these are there and print these separated by comma if aa;bb is there in input file I need aa,bb, if none is there then I need ,, (two commas).

I am using regular expression in each if tho check aa , bb ,cc is any of these are present it will be appended in varible value if it is not there then only , (comma) will be appended in value.

I have created following command.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}  { if( $3 ~ /aa/ ) { value="aa" }  else { value="," }; if( $3 ~ /bb/ ) { value="$value,bb" } else { value="$value," }; 
if( $3 ~ /cc/ ) { value="$value,cc" } else { value="$value,"};  print $1 , $2 , $value}' input.csv > output.csv
```

But it is giving me following output.

```
"11111","TRUE","11111","TRUE","aa"
"456789","TRUE","456789","TRUE","aa;bb;cc"
"2345","TRUE","2345","TRUE","bb"
"434566","","434566","","cc"
```

I am not sure why it is print first two attributes twice and then printing the third value. I am able to do it in shell script but I need to do it using awk.

Comment: what is the logic you are using for these commands ?

Comment: i need first two arguments to be printed everytime but the third one is which i need to check. so third attribute can have any of the aa,bb,cc or combinatination of these like aa;bb or aa;cc or aa;bb;cc or none of these so i need to make sure which of these are there and print these seprated by comma if aa;bb is there in input file i need aa,bb, if none is there then i need ,, (two commas). so i am using regular expresion in each if tho check aa , bb ,cc is any of these are present it will be appended in varible value if it is not there then only ,(comma) will be appended in value .

Comment: Please, read the `awk` basic guides and learn about `awk`, because `print $n` does not print the content of the variable `n` but the nth-field from the input line. So if `n` is a non-integer value (like, for instance, an alphanumeric string) it would converted to an integer value (zero, for instance) and depicts `$0` (the whole input line).

Comment: Thanks alot @Jdamian i got your point. so in this case if i need to use a variable to hold some value and then print it. . is there a way ? or i need to do it using shell script only.

Comment: @amangrewal, Of course, there is a way. Please read this webpage about [awk variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variables) and this other about [input fields](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_20.html#SEC23) in `awk`.

Comment: @Jdamian thanks alot for the help. much appreciated. i will post the solution once i get it after reading about it. thanks once again.

Comment: @amangrewal a shell is an environment from which to call tools. It is **not** a tool to manipulate text. The standard general purpose UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk so whenever you need to manipulate text from a shell, the shell just calls awk, that is all. Don't even think about trying to do any text manipulation using shell - it is incredibly difficult to write efficient, robust shell scripts to do so since it's simply not the job shell was created to do. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks a lot for pointing out. Actually I read the same post a few days ago that`s my main reason for doing this in awk. Thanks a lot for taking out time and helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\""
    split("aa,bb,cc",dflts,/,/)
}
{
    delete vals
    for (i in dflts) {
        vals[i] = ($(NF-1) ~ dflts[i] ? dflts[i] : "")
    }
    $(NF-1) = vals[1] "," vals[2] "," vals[3]
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"11111","TRUE","aa,,"
"456789","TRUE","aa,bb,cc"
"2345","TRUE",",bb,"
"434566","",",,cc"
```

Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: i understood the logic of this code however it is giving me  syntax errors in line 3 and line 8 so i searched about it then i found out that maybe because i am using Solaris and there is standard awk installed . so i changed line 3 of code from split("aa,bb,cc",dflts,/,/) to this split("aa,bb,cc",dflts,",")  now currently i am getting below  syntax error on line 8 which i am unable to solve.                                                                       awk: syntax error near line 8
awk: illegal statement near line 8

Comment: The default awk on Solaris is old, broken awk which must never be used. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (and change the code back to how it is above). There's also nawk on Solaris which basically works too but it's less POSIX-compliant than /usr/xpg4/bin/awk.